# Is it possible to communicate between React Applications?

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

My project is a journey of three react applications, I want to use some data from application 1 to application 2 and application 2 to application 3.

If data to be passed is small, i passed it in query parameter in url of 2nd application.

And if data is large or private, i am planning to send it as a post which will be received by application 2.

Is there any better way of communicating between react applications?
Can i make each reach application as a Library which can expose its data to application 2?

Comment: Were you able to make it work? I have similar kind of problem statement. I have 2 standalone react+Node applications. Now i want to use some functionality of application 2 in my application 1. i want to send some file from application 1 to application 2. then do some computation through user interface on it and after that return it back to application 1. Can you please help me out!!

Comment: React applications do not communicate with each other. You can redirect one React app to external URL which can be another React application but can not share store data. Other possible solution is when one React application exports its components as node module.

Comment: @BalramSingh based on your comment can you have a look at this question and try to answer if you can?- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60005400/react-communication-and-routing-between-components-published-as-npm-packages

Comment: Monorepos are the best solution for above problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Communication between React web apps was not easy in 2016 when I posted this question.

Nowadays, multiple React apps, including React Native apps, can communicate easily by sharing the Redux store, common utilities, common font files and common assets in a common `libs` using Monorepo. I used `Nx` monorepo for this purpose.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use the postMessage ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)), which is now supported in every browser.

It's a cross-domain, event-based messaging system running directly in the browser, with a familiar API.

Be sure to check the message's source before acting on them in your destination page!

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading a new page in between then sending to the server via a post is a good idea.

If you're not then you can set it to some global location like `window.application1Data = { data: data };`

Comment: We can't set it into global variable because data may be senstive