# How to access react global state from App level (for external access via ref)?

Tags: reactjs

I am integrating React into existing page and hence I need to access React from outside. I have set up a global state provider and I do know how to bind reference to react from outside, but I don't know how to access this global state provider from app level.

```
class App extends Component {

  handleSubmit(){
                         // The handleSubmit is fired, when i click button #my_button, which is outside from react app
    console.log(this.context);  // undefined <- how to access the state, provided by SettingsProvider????
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <SettingsProvider>
          <... />
      </SettingsProvider>
    );
  }
}

if (document.getElementById('app')) {
  // find element by id
  const element = document.getElementById('app');

  // Reference react from outside
  const pageComponent = render(<App
    ref={(pageComponent) => {window.pageComponent = pageComponent}}
    />, element);

  // Bind handleSubmit event to external button
  const myButton = document.getElementById("my_button");
  myButton.addEventListener("click", event => {
    alert(window.pageComponent.handleSubmit());
  });
}
```

Comment: This might help https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: Don't know why you need to access app global state, but what you're asking sounds like duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161230/is-it-possible-to-communicate-between-react-applications