# React - Communication and routing between components published as npm packages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, rxjs, react-router

I am trying to setup micro-frontend architecture for the project. The project contains multiple `react` apps. Following is the project structure:

- container
- header (npm package)
- dashboard (npm package)
- app1 (npm package)
- app2 (npm package)
- app3 (npm package)

Here, container works as wrapper for the other apps. Dashboard apps shows links to the other apps such as app1, app2, app3 etc...

Once user logs in header and dashboard app renders on a page. From dashboard user can navigate to other apps.

`container`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Header from 'header';
import Dashboard from 'dashboard';
import { api } from '../api';

function storeUser(user) {
  if (user) {
    localStorage.user = JSON.stringify(user);
  } else {
    delete localStorage.user;
  }
}

function Container() {
  const [error, setError] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  const login = async () => {
    try {
      const user = await api({
        endpoint: 'identity/login',
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
          email: 'test@abc.com',
          password: '12345'
        }
      });
      setUser(user);
      storeUser(user);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" onClick={() => login()}></input>
      {user ? (
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Dashboard />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <span>{error}</span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Container;
```

`dashboard`

```
function Dashboard() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await getApps();
      setData(response);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

**How can I inform `container` that `li` in `dashboard` app (published as npm package) has been clicked and render clicked component/app using `react-router`?**

Comment: why you want to do this using react-router to be exact ?. Can easily be done using a function prop.

Comment: @ZunaibImtiaz I need to inform container that an item has been clicked in dashboard so that container can route and render respected component.

Comment: You dont need to do it like this. Just define your routes and replace `li` tags with `Link` tags provided by `react-router-dom.`

Comment: @ZunaibImtiaz dashboard app is published as npm package and `react-router` will only be included in container app. Not in dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass a prop with a callback to the Dashboard root component and use it as `onClick` handler:

Container:

`<Dashboard onItemClicked={(itemUrl) => this.props.history.push(itemUrl)} />`

Dashboard:

`<li key={item.id} onClick={() => this.props.onItemClicked(item.url)}>{item.name}</li>`

The container component can then use the `history` API to push a different route when this function is called. If container is using `react-router` (and `withRouter`) it should hook into the routing you have set up. A central file where the route paths (strings) are maintained is helpful with this.

Alternatively, you could pass the entire `history` prop to the dashboard.